# Woocommerce api authentication with oauthswift oauth1.0

Tags: ios, swift, api, oauth, woocommerce

Hi I use third party library which is OauthSwift Oauth 1.0 to authorize woo commerce api service but woo commerce return this error "Sorry you can not list resources". I have tried different approaches to solve and authorize but same problem occurred.Does anyone know a solution or help me? I use Swift 2.3 for this project.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qI3H4.png